# Spark SQL - difference between gzip vs snappy vs lzo compression formats

Tags: apache-spark, gzip, parquet, snappy, lzo

I am trying to use Spark SQL to write `parquet` file.

By default Spark SQL supports `gzip`, but it also supports other compression formats like `snappy` and `lzo`.

What is the difference between these compression formats?

Comment: It seems that by default Spark uses "snappy" and not "gzip". At least that's what I see on s3: files created with the string "snappy" as part of their name.

Comment: @bashan: the recent versions of spark changed the default format to snappy, till 1.6.1 i can see the default parquet compression format is gzip.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just try them on your data.

lzo and snappy are fast compressors and very fast decompressors, but with less compression, as compared to gzip which compresses better, but is a little slower.

*Update many years later:*

Also try [lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4) and [zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd).

Answer (score 58):

***Compression Ratio :***
GZIP compression uses more CPU resources than Snappy or LZO, but provides a higher compression ratio.

***General Usage :***
GZip is often a good choice for **cold** data, which is accessed infrequently.
Snappy or LZO are a better choice for **hot** data, which is accessed frequently.

Snappy often performs better than LZO. It is worth running tests to see if you detect a significant difference.

***Splittablity :***
If you need your compressed data to be splittable, BZip2, LZO, and Snappy formats are splittable, but GZip is not.

GZIP compresses data 30% more as compared to Snappy and 2x more CPU when reading GZIP data compared to one that is consuming Snappy data.

LZO focus on decompression speed at low CPU usage and higher compression at the cost of more CPU.

For ***longer term/static*** storage, the GZip compression is still better.

[See  extensive research and  benchmark code and results in this article (***Performance of various general compression algorithms – some of them are unbelievably fast!***).](https://web.archive.org/web/20180818143434/http://java-performance.info/performance-general-compression/)

[image]

Comment: I cannot propose an edit to your nice post, however I'd like to point out that bz2 is indeed splittable natively but Snappy and LZO are spitable by hadoop for hadoop they most likely will not be splittable if generated by other tool than the one provided in hadoop library.

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the article is down, do you happen to know where it moved?

Answer (score 37):

Use Snappy if you can handle higher disk usage for the performance benefits (lower CPU + Splittable).

When Spark switched from GZIP to Snappy by default, this was the reasoning:

> Based on our tests, gzip decompression is very slow (< 100MB/s),
>   making queries decompression bound. Snappy can decompress at ~ 500MB/s
>   on a single core.

Snappy:

- Storage Space: High
- CPU Usage: Low
- Splittable: **Yes** (1)

GZIP:

- Storage Space: Medium
- CPU Usage: Medium
- Splittable: **No**

1) http://boristyukin.com/is-snappy-compressed-parquet-file-splittable/

Comment: That line goes on to say "Snappy and GZip blocks are not splittable, but files with Snappy blocks inside a container file format such as SequenceFile or Avro can be split." We are talking about parquet here. Snappy is splittable when used in Parquet as referenced in the answer.

Comment: That makes sense, sorry I missed the last part in the question. Thanks mate.

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323882/is-gzipped-parquet-file-splittable-in-hdfs-for-spark/43390870 parquet files are splittable independent of the used compression, so I'm not sure the third point in the comparison holds.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the data below,  I'd say `gzip` wins outside of scenarios like streaming, where write-time latency would be important.

It's important to keep in mind that speed is essentially compute cost. However, cloud compute is a one-time cost whereas cloud storage is a recurring cost. The tradeoff depends on the retention period of the data.

---

*Let's test speed and size with large and small `parquet` files in Python.*

**Results (large file, 117 MB):**

```
        +----------+----------+--------------------------+
        | snappy   | gzip     | snappy/gzip              |
+-------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
| write | 1.62 ms  | 7.65 ms  | 4.7x faster              |
+-------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
| size  | 35484122 | 17269656 |    2x larger             |
+-------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
| read  | 973 ms   | 1140 ms  |  1.2x faster             |
+-------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
```

**Results (small file, 4 KB, Iris dataset):**

```
        +---------+---------+--------------------------+
        | snappy  | gzip    | snappy/gzip               |
+-------+---------+---------+--------------------------+
| write | 1.56 ms | 2.09 ms |  1.3x faster             |
+-------+---------+---------+--------------------------+
| size  | 6990    | 6647    |  5.2% smaller            |
+-------+---------+---------+--------------------------+
| read  | 3.22 ms | 3.44 ms |  6.8% slower             |
+-------+---------+---------+--------------------------+
```

---

*small_file.ipynb*

```py
import os, sys
import pyarrow
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
    columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target']
)

# ========= WRITE =========
%timeit df.to_parquet(path='iris.parquet.snappy', compression='snappy', engine='pyarrow', index=True)
# 1.56 ms

%timeit df.to_parquet(path='iris.parquet.gzip', compression='snappy', engine='pyarrow', index=True)
# 2.09 ms

# ========= SIZE =========
os.stat('iris.parquet.snappy').st_size
# 6990

os.stat('iris.parquet.gzip').st_size
# 6647

# ========= READ =========
%timeit pd.read_parquet(path='iris.parquet.snappy', engine='pyarrow')
# 3.22 ms

%timeit pd.read_parquet(path='iris.parquet.gzip', engine='pyarrow')
# 3.44 ms
```

*large_file.ipynb*

```py
import os, sys
import pyarrow
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# ========= WRITE =========
%timeit df.to_parquet(path='file.parquet.snappy', compression='snappy', engine='pyarrow', index=True)
# 1.62 s

%timeit df.to_parquet(path='file.parquet.gzip', compression='gzip', engine='pyarrow', index=True)
# 7.65 s

# ========= SIZE =========
os.stat('file.parquet.snappy').st_size
# 35484122

os.stat('file.parquet.gzip').st_size
# 17269656

# ========= READ =========
%timeit pd.read_parquet(path='file.parquet.snappy', engine='pyarrow')
# 973 ms

%timeit pd.read_parquet(path='file.parquet.gzip', engine='pyarrow')
# 1.14 s
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with 1 answer(@Mark Adler) and have some reserch info[1], but I do not agree with the second answer(@Garren S)[2]. Maybe Garren misunderstood the question, because:
[2] Parquet splitable with all supported codecs:[Is gzipped Parquet file splittable in HDFS for Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323882/is-gzipped-parquet-file-splittable-in-hdfs-for-spark) , Tom White's Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, 4-th edition, Chapter 5: Hadoop I/O, page 106.
[1] My reserch:
source data - 205 GB. Text(separated fields), not compressed.
output data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>time of computing, hours</th>
      <th>volume, GB</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ORC with default codec</td>
      <td>3-3,5</td>
      <td>12.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Parquet with GZIP</td>
      <td>3,5-3,7</td>
      <td>12.9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Parquet with SNAPPY</td>
      <td>2,5-3,0</td>
      <td>60.4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Transformation was performed using Hive on an EMR consisting of 2 m4.16xlarge. 
Transformation - select all fields with ordering by several fields.
This research, of course, is not standard, but at least a little shows the real comparison. With other datasets and computation results may be different.